# Setting Up Azure Front Door to Handle Non Standard Ports

Tags: networking, azure-front-door

I have a front door set up for [www.foo.com](http://www.foo.com) but I need it to be able to handle [www.foo.com:5100](http://www.foo.com:5100) and a list of many other ports. Not sure how I can configure the front door to handle requests other than 80 and 443.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently this cannont be done. I was able to achieve this by using Azure Application Gateway. Much more configurable and has the same WAF capabilities. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/